# Salesforce/Apex - getDescribe by field name

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an Apex Controller that needs to retrieve a field describe based on a field name.  The field name might be something like Account.OwnerId.firstname.  I could accomplish this by recursively doing a describe on Account, then OwnerId, then firstname, but for Orgs with complex schemas I could see running into SF limits using this type of solution.

Is there a way to get the describe for a field by the fully qualified field name?  Or at least get a reference to a Schema.SObjectField instance by the field name so that I only have to do a single describe?

Comment: This is a very salesforce specific question, which may get better responses over at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Much more salesforce people active on that subsite.